# Mysql UPDATE query with two tables

Tags: mysql

I wanted to run this query:

`UPDATE up SET up.pts = uc.checkin_worth WHERE uc.email = up.email AND uc.company_id = up.company_id AND uc.email = 'test@gmail.com' AND uc.company_id = '4' AND uc.qrcode = 'j'`

However, I am getting an error because I don't know how to combine two tables (uc and up) in a UPDATE query.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Thanks,

Comment: when you have a question, it's useful to post information on the aspects of what is being treated; in this case, it'd be nice to see the structure of your tables, to see what may be used to join them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the normal JOIN syntax:

```
UPDATE up JOIN uc ON uc.email = up.email AND uc.company_id = up.company_id
SET up.pts = uc.checkin_worth
WHERE uc.email = 'test@gmail.com' AND uc.company_id = '4' AND uc.qrcode = 'j'
```

You can also use the old comma syntax, which is more similar to your original query:

```
UPDATE uc, up
SET up.pts = uc.checkin_worth
WHERE uc.email = up.email
AND uc.company_id = up.company_id
AND uc.email = 'test@gmail.com'
AND uc.company_id = '4'
AND uc.qrcode = 'j'
```

Comment: I has a typo in my column name, thanks for the help though. I will accept this answer when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
UPDATE up, uc 
SET up.pts = uc.checkin_worth, 
WHERE uc.email = up.email AND uc.company_id = up.company_id AND uc.email = 'test@gmail.com' AND uc.company_id = '4' AND uc.qrcode = 'j'
```